# in python-chess library: "white_clock, white_inc black_clock, black_inc" is internally managed by library? or i need to update it myself?

Tags: python, clock, python-chess

I'm working with python-chess library, i need to know in **python-chess library:** **"white_clock, white_inc black_clock, black_inc"** is internally managed by library? or i need to update it myself?

i have a code like this:

```
limit = chess.engine.Limit(white_clock=10, black_clock=10)
engine_res = await engine.play(board, limit)
```

So library will update its click by itself or i need to change the value in limit every time myself?

Also how to print **remaining time of like say: white_clock**

Answer (score 1):

You have to manage it yourself.